# Why does this strtok() fail when invoked with correct parameter types?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strtok

I've traced an issue in my C program to a call to `strtok()` (whose signature, for the record, is [`char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)). In attempting to recreate the issue in a much simple toy program, I've hit a wall - I'm passing all the correct parameter types and getting a bus error every time I try to run the code.

Here's the program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
     char* tok;
     char* str = "www.example.com";
     const char* split = ".";

     tok = strtok(str, split);
     while(tok != NULL) {
         printf("%s\n", tok);
         tok = strtok(NULL, split);
     }
}
```

Oddly enough, I've found that declaring `str` as an array (`char str[] = "www.example.com"`) and passing a reference to `str` to the initial strtok call (`tok = strtok(&str, split)`) does seem to work properly.

I'm not really worried about functionality here - the solution using an array works. I'm curious about why the original implementation, which uses a pointer to a `char`, fails and throws a bus error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of

```
 char* str = "www.example.com";
 /// some code
 tok = strtok(str, split);
```

you're using a (pointer to) *string literal* as the first parameter. As `strtok()` may try to alter the content of first argument passed to it, you'll face  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> These functions modify their first argument.  [...]

and regarding attempted alteration to a string literal, from `C11`, chapter §6.4.5

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined

OTOH, if you create an array, initialize it with the string literal and pass the array to `strtok()`, it is perfectly fine, as your array is modifiable by your program.